# Weasyprint django - generates an empty PDF

Tags: javascript, python, django, pdf, weasyprint

Good afternoon,

I have the following problem in my app:

I am working on generating pdfs via WEASYPRINT for some of my views. My app is a search engine that aggregates external information, what I am looking for is:

- That the user makes a search and the results are shown.
- When he clicks on report, he can download a pdf with the search results. (via AJAX without having to reload the page).

So far this works perfect using xhtml2pdf, but I want to change it to WEASYPRINT because it allows more flexibility in the design of the pdf.

As I said there is an ajax function that sends the data to the pdf generation view, it receives them and generates a pdf with converting the html to pdf and sends a response that with a ".done()' function in javascript activates the download of the pdf. The problem is that this pdf is shown empty because there must be some decoding problem, or so I think.

Views.py

```
def ViewPDF(request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = request.POST.get('nombre', None)
    hits = request.POST.get('hits', None)
    
    response2 = request.POST.get('query1', None)
    
    info = {'searched': str(response2), 'customer': request.user.customer.name, 'type_of_search': '',
            'lists_covered': 'OFAC', 'Date_of_search': str(request.POST.get('date', None)), 'hits': hits}

    if response is not None:
        # json_search = json.loads(response2)

        if hits == 'YES':
            json_data = json.loads(response)

            info['type_of_search'] = 'basic search'

            data = []
            
            for i in range(len(json_data)):
                data.append({'body': {
                    'Name': json_data[i]['name'],
                    'Description': json_data[i]['notes'],
                    'Occupation': json_data[i]['ocupation'],
                    'Place_of_Birth': json_data[i]['POB'],
                    'Date_of_Birth': json_data[i]['DOB'],
                    'Position': json_data[i]['other'],
                    'Citizenship': json_data[i]['nationality']
                }})

            data = {'info': info, 'body': data}

            template = get_template('core/reports/free_search.html')
            html = template.render(data)  
            

            
            pdf = HTML(string=html).write_pdf()
            
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'utf-8'
               
            
            
        
  
            
            if request.is_ajax():

              
              
                return response
```

main.js

```
                var url = '/pdf/' + query['s_pk']
                $report0 = $('#report');
                $report0.on('click', function () {
                    

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            query1: query['search'],
                            nombre: JSON.stringify(query['responseData']),
                            date: $time,
                            hits: 'YES',
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                        }
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        
                        let blob = new Blob([response]);
                        let link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = query['search'] + '.pdf';
                        link.click();
                    });
```

The response to the request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEYXg.png)

I guess it has something to do with encoding, but I would appreaciate some help here... Where do you think is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it in the following way

[image: Solution]